# How do cmake configuration and default build task configuration play together in VSCode?

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code, cmake, g++

I'm compiling this [PCL Library example](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_pcl_pcl_config.html#using-pcl-pcl-config). For reference, it consists of a simple cpp file that includes some PCL headers and does some basic data manipulation, and a CMakeLists.txt file.

Using the command line, I am able to build it using cmake -> make. I want to build it also using VSCode IDE. When I open this project on VSCode, it detects I'm using cmake, and if I clean/build it using the cmake extension, everything seems to work as expected (including autocompletion by intellisense, etc).

However, this takes some time as it builds the whole project in the same way you would do it from the command line, only from VSCode. I wanted to understand if I can also configure a "default build task" (via the tasks.json file) to build files using Ctrl + Shift + B, and be able to build individual files, and have a more IDE-Like experience (something like the incremental compiler of Eclipse with Java, for example).

If I add a C++ configuration, it fails to find .h files, and errors are highlighted on the open file, until I clean/rebuild via de cmake extension.

My question is, are this two options (cmake extension vs build tasks) compatible or mutually exclusive? Is defining and compiling via a task in fact more agile than building via the cmake extension?

Thanks!